How to upload html files on a SSRS 2022 Reportserver?
In SSRS 2016 it is possible to upload not only RDLs but also Html files. In SSRS 2022 its not possible because of security reasons. Question is it possible to change in with the rsreportserver.config or web.config file?
The Llame3 Chatbot told me I need to just change the rsreportserver.config and add this line
<Security>
    ...
    <AllowedFileExtensions>
        <Extension>.html</Extension>
    </AllowedFileExtensions>
    ...
</Security>

I did it but then the reportserver did not run. Seems not to work. Are the any other ideas?

From Management Studio connect to your report server.
Right click on the server and click Properties.
On the Advanced page there is a property AllowedResourceExtensionsForUpload.
Add the *.html and *.htm extension to allow uploading html files.

The setting is stored in the SSRS database, you could use the following query to update it.
UPDATE c SET Value = CAST([Value] AS NVARCHAR(4000)) + N', *.html, *.htm'
FROM  [dbo].[ConfigurationInfo] c
WHERE Name = 'AllowedResourceExtensionsForUpload'

The change doesn't need a service restart.

Yes you right. I can then upload this files. But I can not access this files. If I then click on it, then the browser just download the file but do not display the html content like in SSRS 2016. Is it possible to change?

I don't know if there are other settings in the database or SSRS configurations files that allows that. If you have SSRS 2016 available try to compare the settings referring to HTML rendering and file type extensions with SSRS 2019
